# How to export the Subversion log to spreadsheet

Tags: xml, svn, logging, tortoisesvn, spreadsheet

Is there a way to export the Subversion log messages to a spreadsheet(excel, csv, etc.) format?

When copying from the Log Messages window in TortoiseSVN, it pastes text in the following format:

```
Revision: 174
Author: CARDINALHEALTH\enrique.colon
Date: Wednesday, July 11, 2012 9:37:02 AM
Message: CR #58514
----
Modified : /trunk/ob_progs/utility/connect_peek
```

I could create a script to reformat this to CSV, if necessary.  But I really don't want to :(

Answer (score 43, accepted):

1. Use the following Subversion command to create an xml file out of the repository's log:

   **svn log -v --xml > repository_log.xml**
2. Import the xml file into an **Excel** spreadsheet (not sure if it will work with LibreOffice/OpenOffice), e.g. from cmd:

   **start excel repository_log.xml**
3. You can then save it as a spreadsheet.

**That's it!**

Comment: This works great, the only extra step I had to do was to open the xml in Notepad++ and save the encoding as ANSI before Excel would import.

Answer (score 29):

Since you are using TortoiseSVN and are thus on Windows, a straightforward way to do this is with PowerShell. Start with this function to convert svn log data to PowerShell objects:

```
Function Get-SvnLogData()
{
    ([xml](svn log -v --xml)).log.logentry | % {
        $nestedEntry = $_
        $_.paths.path | % {
            $path = $_
            $nestedEntry | Select-Object -Property `
                Author, `
                @{n='Revision'; e={([int]$_.Revision)}}, `
                @{n='Date';     e={Get-Date $_.Date  }}, `
                @{n='Action';   e={$path.action      }}, `
                @{n='Path';     e={$path.InnerText   }}`
        }
    }
}
```

The default output is a list, e.g.:

```
author   : smith
Revision : 29091
Date     : 6/26/2012 7:30:44 AM
Action   : M
Path     : /Utility/trunk/Distribution/file1.txt

author   : jones
Revision : 28987
Date     : 6/21/2012 3:56:51 PM
Action   : M
Path     : /Utility/trunk/Distribution/file2.txt

author   : msorens
Revision : 28934
Date     : 6/21/2012 8:22:17 AM
Action   : M
Path     : /Utility/trunk/Distribution/file3.txt

author   : jones
Revision : 28835
Date     : 6/19/2012 8:56:08 AM
Action   : A
Path     : /Utility/trunk/DAL/stuff.txt
. . .
```

---

With this command, however...

```
Get-SvnLogData | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

...you can tell PowerShell to give you a table instead of a list, e.g.:

```
author     Revision Date                   Action Path
------     -------- ----                   ------ ----
smith         29091 6/26/2012 7:30:44 AM   M      /Utility/trunk/Distribution/file1.txt
jones         28987 6/21/2012 3:56:51 PM   M      /Utility/trunk/Distribution/file2.txt
msorens       28934 6/21/2012 8:22:17 AM   M      /Utility/trunk/Distribution/file3.txt
jones         28835 6/19/2012 8:56:08 AM   A      /Utility/trunk/DAL/stuff.txt
. . .
```

---

And to actually answer your question :-) you can just as easily convert the output to CSV and send it to a file with a command like this:

```
Get-SvnLogData | Export-Csv -Path temp.csv
```

Double-clicking on the resultant file opens it up in Excel:

[image: SVN to Excel]

Comment: Wow, just awesome, I didn't know what PowerShell was, thanks to this, I'm not discovering a new tool. The script to export the log was perfect also. +1

Comment: Note you can grab any attribute in the XML output, for example I was also interested in the Message which can be gotten by adding the following line (in the appropriate place):

    @{n='Message';   e={$_.msg      }}

Comment: I love powershell and I love this answer, FANTASTIC!  My repo has tons of commits so I retrieved only the last 20 as follows: `Get-SvnLogData | sort-Object @{Expression="Date"; Descending=$true} | Select-Object -first 20 | Export-Csv -Path temp.csv`

Answer (score 2):

Chris West came up with a pretty simple and yet effective solution:  <s>http://gotochriswest.com/blog/2012/10/02/svn-log-to-csv-converter/</s>
Actually the page seems to be moved here:
http://cwestblog.com/2012/10/02/svn-log-to-csv-converter/

He listed two solutions on that page.  The first is a Java program which will output a CSV.  The second is a JSBin page which will convert the pasted SVN log into a CSV.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Michael Sorens is awesome and this is how I extract SVN log data.  I am posting a supplemental answer which shows you how to apply his solution into a script file that can be run in an instant.

Create and save the script seen below to .PS1 file.  Open and view the file in basic Notepad program.  Then pin the file.  Now all you have to do is right click my Notepad task bar icon, hover of the file, right-click the file, from the fly out window choose "Run with PowerShell".  In an instance the CSV data file pops up, and for me it opens in Excel.

About the script file that you may want to review and revise.

- My repo has tons of commits so I retrieved only the last 20
- Update the filepaths
- Used the Invoke-Item cmdlet to [Opening the output file automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40163076/opening-the-output-file-automatically/40163845)
- As suggested in this thread you could add `@{n='Message'; e={$_.msg }}`

**Get-SvnLogData.ps1**

```
# Get-SvnLogData | sort-Object @{Expression="Date"; Descending=$true} | Select-Object -first 20 | Export-Csv -Path temp.csv

#############################################################
# <STEP 1: MUST FIRST CREATE THIS FUNCTION.....>
    Function Get-SvnLogData()
    {
        ([xml](svn log -v --xml)).log.logentry | % {
            $nestedEntry = $_
            $_.paths.path | % {
                $path = $_
                $nestedEntry | Select-Object -Property `
                    Author, `
                    @{n='Revision'; e={([int]$_.Revision)}}, `
                    @{n='Date';     e={Get-Date $_.Date  }}, `
                    @{n='Action';   e={$path.action      }}, `
                    @{n='Path';     e={$path.InnerText   }}`
            }
        }
    }
# <\STEP 1>

# <STEP 2: NAVIGATE TO THE DIRECTORY.....>
    cd \

    cd SVN\BusinessAnalysts\SSRSReports\ssrs2016_solution
# <\STEP 2>

# <STEP 3: EXTRACT THE LOGDATA TO CSV; OPEN THE FILE.....>    
    Get-SvnLogData | sort-Object @{Expression="Date"; Descending=$true} | Select-Object -first 20 | Export-Csv -Path temp.csv

    #REM https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/399abe9a-195c-4362-9081-6fd9d79b88ad/need-help-converting-getlocation-info-to-string?forum=winserverpowershell 
    $CurrentDirectory= get-location
    $path = $CurrentDirectory.tostring() + "\"

    Invoke-Item $path"temp.csv"
# <\STEP 3>

#############################################################
```

**TUTORIAL: PS1 file - Run with PowerShell**

[image]