# Set Minimum Issue Number in Gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab

We are migrating from subversion to git and we've decided to use Gitlab as the web interface. We reference an issue number in our commit messages.  Since we are using Gitlab's issue tracker, the number would reset to 1. For a given project, how can I set the minimum issue number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there is no official way to do this.  I actually just used the Gitlab API in Ruby to create a bunch of dummy issues and close them.  I'm sure that if I was really adventurous I could probably export the existing issues from our current VCS or something, but for our purposes it works just to do that.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's an official way to accomplish this. You're probably going to need to get your hands dirty in the database to get it done. I would try to create a dummy issue in your project which will create issue 1. Then go into the database, find the `issues` table and edit the `position` column to the number one before you want to start with then resolve it. In theory, the next issue created would be the number you want to start with.

I haven't tested this. If it does work, it is possible it could cause long term problems break with other functionality or issues with future upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

`Gitlab` allows exporting to and importing from .csv.

`Subversion` also exports to XML that is importable to an excel-like program.
(I found [How to export the Subversion log to spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11436214/how-to-export-the-subversion-log-to-spreadsheet))

I haven't tried that, but I suggest that

- Columns won't fit
- It's not painful to make the entries from one file be copied correctly to  fit Gitlab's .csv layout

That makes importing a prepared .csv an option.

Answer (score 0):

Hello from far in the future (for anyone that is looking for another method). Another unofficial way to do this (in 2023) is to create a CSV with the appropriate number of filler rows, and import that into GitLab. I recommend giving each issue the same name, making it easier to search and close the issues in batch later.

I have confirmed that this method works as desired