# Opening the output file automatically

Tags: powershell

I have a script that creates a csv file which I then go open to get the information I am looking for. Is there a way to add to the script so that the file opens immediately as well as saves in the specified location?

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter { Enabled -eq $true } -Properties Name -SearchBase          
"DC=REMOVED,DC=com" | 
Select Name |
? {$_. Name -like "X*" } |
Export-Csv "C:\scripts\Computers.csv"
```

Comment: Open in what program? 
`c:\pathToProgram.exe C:\scripts\Computers.csv` will likely work...

Comment: Excel. The path to Excel.exe for me is: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.exe so would I use that followed by the path of the script? I tried that just now to check and wasn't finding any success.

Comment: Try `start C:\scripts\Computers.csv`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add this quick snippet to the end of your code:

```
Invoke-Item "C:\scripts\Computers.csv"
```

If you have Excel automatically configured to support/open `.csv` files, it should open automatically.

EDIT: Note that this isn't available in Powershell 2.0 - only 3.0+